# Null reference when printing WPF FixedPage in Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I have a .net framework v4.7.2 WPF application that prints a `FixedPage` that has been running without any issues on Windows 7, but I've ran into some issues when running it on Windows 8.1.

The following code block is what causing the troubles:

```cs
private void Print()
{
    using (var printQueue = LocalPrintServer.GetDefaultPrintQueue())
    {
        var printTicket = printQueue.DefaultPrintTicket;
        var writer = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(printQueue);
        writer.WritingCompleted += OnDocumentWritten;
        writer.WriteAsync(View.LabelPageView.AddressLabelPage, printTicket);
    }
}
```

It throws a `NullReferenceException` with the following stack trace:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Collections.Hashtable.get_Item(Object key)
   at System.Printing.PrintQueue.get_IsXpsDevice()
   at System.Printing.PrintQueue.ForwardXpsDriverDocEvent(Object sender, XpsSerializationXpsDriverDocEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Xps.Serialization.XpsSerializationManager.OnXpsDriverDocEvent(XpsSerializationXpsDriverDocEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Xps.Serialization.XpsDriverDocEventManager.OnXpsDriverDocEvent()
   at System.Windows.Xps.Serialization.XpsDriverDocEventManager.ForwardPackagingProgressEvent(Object sender, PackagingProgressEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Xps.Packaging.PackagingProgressEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, PackagingProgressEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Xps.Packaging.XpsInterleavingPolicy.AddItem(INode n, Int32 number, INode parent)
   at System.Windows.Xps.Serialization.XpsPackagingPolicy.AcquireXmlWriterForFixedPage()
   at System.Windows.Xps.Serialization.XpsSerializationManager.AcquireXmlWriter(Type writerType)
   at System.Windows.Xps.Serialization.FixedPageSerializerAsync.get_XmlWriter()
   at System.Windows.Xps.Serialization.ReachTreeWalker..ctor(ReachSerializer serializer)
   at System.Windows.Xps.Serialization.FixedPageSerializerAsync.PersistObjectData(SerializableObjectContext serializableObjectContext)
   at System.Windows.Xps.Serialization.ReachSerializerAsync.BeginSerializeObject(Object serializedObject)
   at System.Windows.Xps.Serialization.FixedPageSerializerAsync.SerializeObject(Object serializedObject)
   at System.Windows.Xps.Serialization.XpsSerializationManagerAsync.InvokeSaveAsXamlWorkItem(Object arg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

If i replace `writer.WriteAsync(...)` with `writer.Write(...)` the error disappears.

I have been able to reproduce the error on Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012 R2 and Windows Server 2016. I have not been able to reproduce the error on Windows 10.

Any suggestions on how to print asynchronously on Windows 8.1?

Comment: You probably need to keep the reference to that instance in printQueue alive, or at least don't call Dispose on it till printing has finished. It looks like you can defer Disposing to the OnDocumentWritten method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @rene the OP is using an async method inside the `using` block without awaiting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@rene 's answer fixed the issue, so apparently the issue was that the PrintQueue was disposed before the printing finished.

```cs
private void Print()
{
    var printQueue = LocalPrintServer.GetDefaultPrintQueue()
    var printTicket = printQueue.DefaultPrintTicket;
    var writer = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(printQueue);
    writer.WritingCompleted += OnDocumentWritten;
    writer.WriteAsync(View.LabelPageView.AddressLabelPage, printTicket);
}
```

It does however seem odd, that the code worked on Windows 10 but not Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 2):

You could make the method `async` and then `await` the async call.

Try this:

```
private async Task Print()
{
    using (var printQueue = LocalPrintServer.GetDefaultPrintQueue())
    {
        var printTicket = printQueue.DefaultPrintTicket;
        var writer = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(printQueue);
        writer.WritingCompleted += OnDocumentWritten;
        await writer.WriteAsync(View.LabelPageView.AddressLabelPage, printTicket);
    }
}
```